# MySQL - rand from the defined values

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to insert random values to tables. But I don't want to make new values totally random (like eg: random numbers or characters),I want to take a random value from a set of values defined earlier. For example:
defined values: xyz, abc, edf
random value: abc

I programming languages it's very easy, but in SQL I don't know, how to store this defined values and how to take random value.

Answer (score 2):

Put your random values in a table.

Then, you can insert them one at a time by doing:

```
insert into tables(val)
    select val
    from randomtable
    order by rand()
    limit 1
```

The `order by rand() limit 1` chooses a random value from your list.

Comment: Great, it will be very helpful for me! Thanks!